# Matching button background to list background

Tags: html, css

I want to match the color of the Connect as button on my navbar to the rest of the list but its always darker

```
.dropdown{
     background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  }
```

**[FULL CODE HERE](https://codepen.io/norelhouda/pen/MRMGrw)**

Comment: Try replacing `background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.4);`  of `.dropbtn` with `background: transparent;`

Comment: Also, once this is done, if you want the whole bar lighter, change `rgba(255,255,255,0.4)` of `nav_ul` to `rgba(255,255,255,0.7)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `'Connect as'` button has a declared class `'dropbtn'`, it will override the CSS `'color'` you declared in your CSS block `'nav ul li a'` by CSS specificity as a class has more weight than element tag, try removing the CSS color property on the `.dropbtn` class and add it to the `'.dropbtn:hover'` in order to trigger the dark color of the text only when hovered

```
.dropbtn:hover{
 color: black;
 background-color:#283fb8 
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

Some notes, at least try separating your CSS in its own file and just add it via link, makes it a lot easier to debug and see the problem. It also cleaner and promotes re-usability. Don't know if I got to answer what you ask here, but hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
.dropbtn{
      color: #fff;
}
.dropbtn:hover {
      background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood and reading your code I think I found the fix you were looking for. On my end it was line 160 on CodePen:

> .dropbtn:hover{background-color:#eee}

The reason the colors didn't match was because you had overridden your previous hover code and since it was lower on the list it took precedents. To fix it you can remove the code or change the color value to this:

> .dropbtn:hover{ background-color: #000 }